# How to assign names to a numeric vector in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

This should be a really straightforward thing, however I am getting trouble assigning names to a numeric vector.

My code is as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
library(labelled)

CIS = read_spss("CISData.sav") %>%
  mutate(
    RECUERDO = to_factor(RECUERDO))

include = c(21, 2, 4, 1, 18)

Voters <- ggplot(CIS %>% filter(RECUERDO %in% include), aes(x = RECUERDO)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "Brown") +
  xlab("Voting Preference in 2019 Spanish General Elections") +
  ylab("Count")

Voters
```

It works perfectly fine and it produces the following graph:

[image: Graph]

*However, what I wish to achieve is to have in the graph "Unidas Podemos" instead of "21", "PSOE" instead of "2", "Ciudadanos" instead of "4", "PP" instead of "1", and "VOX" instead of "18".*

So far, I have tried `setNames` in `stats`, `set_names` in `magrittr`, as well as directly assigning the variables; but nothing of this has worked.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `magrittr` has no functions for dealing with names, it is just providing the `%>%` in your code here, nothing more, nothing relevant to names; at best you should be looking into `dplyr`-related things (I changed the tags), since `filter` is from there, and dplyr has the ability to work with names. Having said that, I think the approach would better be how to deal with the `factor` levels present in `RECUERDO` instead, as ggplot2 is using those levels/labels to add to the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Set the correct factor names before you plot it. If you don't want to change the existing variable, you can always create a new one instead, but I'm just renaming your original variable below. The following should work. Your code is not reproducible, but ggplot plots factors in the order that they are in, so I'm assuming the order on the plot is what would be returned by `levels(CIS$RECUERDO)` before renaming the levels.

```
CIS = read_spss("CISData.sav") %>%  
    filter(RECUERDO %in% c(21, 2, 4, 1, 18)) %>%
    mutate(RECUERDO = to_factor(RECUERDO))

# rename levels of RECUERDO
# make sure the order of the new names matches the order of old factor names 
levels(CIS$RECUERDO) <- c("PP", "PSOE", "Ciudadanos", "VOX", "Unidas Podemos")
```

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for your answer, @cfriess! Also, welcome to the forum! I have tried to run your code, however I get the following error (and I really don't know why): ```Error in `levels<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, value = c("PP", "PSOE", "Ciudadanos",  : 
  number of levels differs``` . Do you know by chance why is this error produced? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I've made sure, by the way, that the order of the new names matches the order of old factor names.

Comment: @ArtUr693 - you could get that error for example if the number of old unique factor names differs from the number of new unique factor names. do you have a reproducible code example?

Comment: @ArtUr693 - ok, I figured out why the original code didn't work. you have to filter before you turn it into a factor, or else it retains all the old factor levels. I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found the correct answer on how to do it! Here it is:

```
#Composition of respondents according to which political party they voted for in 2019 Spanish General Elections 

library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
library(labelled)

CIS = read_spss("CISData.sav") %>%   
    mutate(RECUERDO = to_factor(RECUERDO)) %>%  
    filter(RECUERDO %in% c(21, 2, 4, 1, 18))

CIS$RECUERDO = factor(CIS$RECUERDO, labels=c("PP", "PSOE", "Ciudadanos", "VOX", "Unidas Podemos"))

Voters <- ggplot(CIS, aes(x = RECUERDO)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "Brown") +
  xlab("Voting Preference in 2019 Spanish General Elections") +
  ylab("Count")

Voters
```